# Query data from Google Sheets-based table in BigQuery via API using service account

Tags: google-bigquery, google-oauth, google-cloud-iam

I can fetch data from native BigQuery tables using a service account.

However, I encounter an error when attempting to `select` from a Google Sheets-based table in BigQuery using the same service account.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(
    json_credentials_path='creds.json',
    project='xxx',
)

# this works fine
print('test basic query: select 1')
job = client.run_sync_query('select 1')
job.run()
print('results:', list(job.fetch_data()))
print('-'*50)

# this breaks
print('attempting to fetch from sheets-based BQ table')
job2 = client.run_sync_query('select * from testing.asdf')
job2.run()
```

The output:

```
⚡  ~/Desktop ⚡  python3 bq_test.py
test basic query: select 1
results: [(1,)]
--------------------------------------------------
attempting to fetch from sheets-based BQ table
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bq_test.py", line 16, in <module>
    job2.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/query.py", line 381, in run
    method='POST', path=path, data=self._build_resource())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 293, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.cloud.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/warby-parker-1348/queries: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found.
```

I've attempted to use `oauth2client.service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials` for explicitly defining `scopes`, including a scope for `drive`, but I get the following error when attempting to do so:

```
ValueError: This library only supports credentials from google-auth-library-python. See https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core/auth.html for help on authentication with this library.
```

My understanding is that auth is handled via IAM now, but I don't see any roles to apply to this service account that have anything to do with drive.

**How can I select from a sheets-backed table using the BigQuery python client?**

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I've run into the same issue.

Answer (score 7):

I've ran into the same issue and figured out how to solve it.

When exploring [`google.cloud.bigquery.Client`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py) class, there is a global variable tuple [`SCOPE`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py#L123) that is not being updated by any arguments nor by any `Credentials` object, persisting its default value to the classes that follows its use.

To solve this, you can simply add a new scope URL to the `google.cloud.bigquery.Client.SCOPE` tuple.

In the following code I add the Google Drive scope to it:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

#Add any scopes needed onto this scopes tuple.
scopes = (
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
)

bigquery.Client.SCOPE+=scopes

client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(
    json_credentials_path='/path/to/your/credentials.json',
    project='your_project_name',
)
```

With the code above you'll be able to query data from Sheets-based tables in BigQuery.

Hope it helps!

Comment: oh my god this is such a life saver. Thank you so much. I tried other fixes I found but they just give out different errors.

Comment: this is still a life saver in 2022

Comment: ...still a lifesaver in 2023. it’s a shame that the error messages is so opaque, and that the google python library auth is so byzantine as to require these sorts of work arounds

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right that you need to pass the scope for gdrive when authenticating. The scopes are passed here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/core/google/cloud/client.py#L126 and it seems like the BigQuery client lacks these scopes https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py#L117 . I suggest asking on github and also as a workaround you can try to override client credentials including gdrive scope, but you'll need to use google.auth.credentials from GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python instead of oauth2client, as error message suggests.